# Nginx rewrite issue

Tags: nginx, http, rewrite

I would like a particular configuration for one of my virtual servers but I have a problem explaining that to Nginx :)

Its quite simple. If the URI looks like

```
example.com/whatever_1/whatever_2/.../whatever_n
```

I would like to rewrite it as

```
example.com/index.php?request=whatever_1/whatever_2/.../whatever_n
```

The second is if the URI begins with `/administration/` like

```
example.com/administration/whatever_1/.../whatever_n
```

I would like it to be rewritten as

```
example.com/administration/index.php?request=whatever_1/.../whatever_n
```

I was tinkering arround and tried:

```
server
{
#   listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    index index.html index.php;
    root /srv/example/;

    location ~ /administration/(.*)$
    {
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /administration/index.php?request=$1 last;
        }
        break; #tried with and without it
    }

    location / #tried with and without this location block
    {
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ #boilerplate
        {
                # Filter out arbitrary code execution
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

But this does not work. Im quite new to Nginx so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Jan.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/try_files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nginx, not apache. You should avoid rewrites when possible (and it often is possible).

Use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files) instead. For example:

```
location /administration/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /administration/index.php?request=$request_uri;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?request=$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why should I avoid rewrites?

Comment: Rewrites are slow, and there's usually a faster alternative (such as `return` or `try_files`). And rewrites are often combined with `if` which, while it's valid to do so, can lead to problems (since [`if` is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)).